# When is a UIKeyboardWillShow notification posted?

Tags: ios

The [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification.name/1621576-uikeyboardwillshow) say:

> Posted immediately prior to the display of the keyboard.

But the notification will be posted every time the user changes `UITextFields` regardless of whether the keyboard is up or down. Exactly when is this this notification posted?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209499/avoid-view-when-opening-keyboard-from-a-uitextview-inside-a-uitableview-with-cus

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik there's nothing in that link that attempts to answer my question